# wrote a code for race in java won't work

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java and I wrote this Race program. I tried to run it, but it gave an Illegal Monitor State Exception Error in Race and RaceMain class... can you help?

```
public class RaceMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{     
        Pitstop p = new Pitstop();
        Race r = new Race();
        new Car("Ryan Hunter", r, p);
        new Car("Takumo Sato", r, p);
        new Car("Scott Dixon", r, p);
        new Car("Sebastien Bourdais", r, p);
        r.StartRace();
    }
}

public class Race {
int rank = 0;

    void getToStart() throws InterruptedException{
        wait();
    }

    void StartRace() throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        notifyAll();
    }

    synchronized void FinishRace(Car c){
        rank = rank +1;
        System.out.println("<<<<<<" + c.name + " finished " + geth(rank) + ">>>>>>");
    }

    String geth(int i){
        switch(i % 10){
        case 1:
            return i + "st";
        case 2:
            return i + "nd";
        case 3: 
            return i +"rd";
        default:
            return i + "th";
        }
    }
}

public class Car implements Runnable{
String name;
Race r;
Pitstop p;
int rand;
int lapsCompleted;
boolean needRep = false;

Car(String n, Race r, Pitstop p){
    name = n;
    this.r = r;
    this.p = p;
}

public void run(){
    try{
        r.getToStart();
        System.out.println(name + " is off and speeding!");
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            if(needRep){
                p.repair(name);
                needRep = false;
            }
            runLap();
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

void runLap() throws InterruptedException{
    rand = (int)(Math.random() % 500) + 1000;
    Thread.sleep(rand);
    System.out.println(name + " completed his " + geth(lapsCompleted) + " lap");
    if(Math.floor(Math.random()*10) == 5){
        System.out.println("Oh snap! Looks like " + name + "'s tire has got bursted during the race!");
        needRep = true;
    }
}   

String geth(int i){
    switch(i % 10){
        case 1:
            return i + "st";
        case 2:
            return i + "nd";
        case 3: 
            return i +"rd";
        default:
            return i + "th";
        }
    }
}


public class Pitstop {
    synchronized void repair(String n) throws InterruptedException{
        int dur = (int) (Math.random() * 1000) % 1000 + 5000;
        Thread.sleep(dur);
        double sec = dur / 1000;
        System.out.println(n + " stopped for " + sec);
   }

}
```

Comment: read the complete message of your error

Comment: Your program probably printed a stack trace when it threw the exception.  The stack trace tells you exactly which line of your code was executing when it happened.  If you looked at that line it would have been the .wait() or the .notify() call.  If you had then looked at the javado for .wait() or .notify() it would have told you why either one of them throws that exception and what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to run multiple threads, since `Car` implements `Runnable`?

This would be the correct approach:

```
    Pitstop p = new Pitstop();
    Race r = new Race();
    new Thread(new Car("Ryan Hunter", r, p)).start();
    new Thread(new Car("Takumo Sato", r, p)).start();
    new Thread(new Car("Scott Dixon", r, p)).start();
    new Thread(new Car("Sebastien Bourdais", r, p)).start();
    r.StartRace();
```

Now as far as these 2 methods go, I would remove them completely. Firstly because they are being incorrectly called from the wrong thread, and secondly because I don't see their purpose:

```
void getToStart() throws InterruptedException{
    // remove this
}

void StartRace() throws InterruptedException{
    // remove this
}
```

Now you could add a `Thread.yield` in the run method, like this:

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(name + " is off and speeding!");
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                if (needRep) {
                    p.repair(name);
                    needRep = false;
                }
                runLap();
                Thread.yield();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Results:

```
    Takumo Sato is off and speeding!
    Sebastien Bourdais is off and speeding!
    Ryan Hunter is off and speeding!
    Scott Dixon is off and speeding!
    Ryan Hunter completed his 1st lap
    Scott Dixon completed his 1st lap
    Sebastien Bourdais completed his 1st lap
    Takumo Sato completed his 1st lap
    Oh snap! Looks like Ryan Hunter's tire has got bursted during the race!
    Scott Dixon completed his 2nd lap
    Sebastien Bourdais completed his 2nd lap
    Takumo Sato completed his 2nd lap
    Scott Dixon completed his 3rd lap
    Oh snap! Looks like Scott Dixon's tire has got bursted during the race!
    Sebastien Bourdais completed his 3rd lap
    Takumo Sato completed his 3rd lap
    Oh snap! Looks like Takumo Sato's tire has got bursted during the race!
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two methods that are part of your race code that need to be synchronized:

> ```
> void getToStart() throws InterruptedException{
>     wait();
> }
>
> void StartRace() throws InterruptedException{
>     Thread.sleep(1000);
>     notifyAll();
> }
> ```

Both of those methods call other methods that are only valid when inside a synchronized block:

- [Object.wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--): throws IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.
- [Object.notifyAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--) throws IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of this object's monitor.

Your methods need to be synchronized:

```
synchronized void getToStart() throws InterruptedException{
    wait();
}

synchronized void StartRace() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    notifyAll();
}
```